# Input base on some value changed

Tags: admin-on-rest

```
function Form(props) {
  var objBarCode;
  if (props.record && props.record.type === "STOCK") {
    objBarCode = < TextInput source="barcode" label="Bar Code" / >;
  }
  return (
    < SimpleForm {...props} >
      < TextInput source="item" label="item" validate={[required]} / >
      < TextInput source="name" label="Name" validate={[required]} / >
      < SelectInput
        source="type"
        label="Type"
        validate={[required]}
        choices={[
          { id: "STOCK", name: "Stock" },
          { id: "RMK", name: "Remark" },
          { id: "SVR", name: "Services" }
        ]}
      / >
      {objBarCode}
    < /SimpleForm >
  );
}
```

How can I achieve something like this, where some inputs only appear by some conditions? The above code does not rerender when the condition value changes. The goal was to have the Textinput Bar Code  only appear when `type="STOCK"`

Answer (score 3):

This won't be easy. You'll have to implement a custom input which will get the current value for the condition from the redux form state and decide what to display accordingly.

I suggest you create it as a wrapper or HOC so that you can reuse it.

You'll also have to explore the Admin-on-rest source to find the form key in redux and redux-form documentation for how to get the value.

However as this is a very common scenario, I'll see what we can do to make it easier:

We just released [aor-dependent-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aor-dependent-input) ! Let us know if that works for you :)

Comment: I'm working on a solution for this use case. It will probably be published next week, either as a plugin package for Admin-on-rest or bundled in it. I'll let you know :)

Comment: We just released [aor-dependent-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aor-dependent-input) ! Let us know if that works for you :)